# Is it possible to capture a block of nested HTML with PCRE RegEx?

Tags: html, regex, pcre

Before you slate me, yes I know that you *shouldn't* parse HTML with regex, you should use a dedicated parser. I don't have that option in the language I'm using (Xojo) and for various reasons, I need to use RegEx.

I'm trying to capture an entire block of HTML that may or may not contain nested HTML elements. Examples:

```
<blockquote> This is a blockquote with two paragraphs. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
 consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aliquam hendrerit mi posuere lectus.
 Vestibulum enim wisi, viverra nec, fringilla in, laoreet vitae, risus.

 Donec sit amet nisl. Aliquam semper ipsum sit amet velit. Suspendisse
 id sem consectetuer libero luctus adipiscing.</blockquote>

 -----------------

<blockquote> This is the first level of quoting.

<blockquote> This is nested blockquote.</blockquote>
 Back to the first level.</blockquote>

 -----------------

<div>
Not nested
</div>

 -----------------

<div>
Top level
<div>Nested</div>
</div>
```

I had come up with this pattern: `<(\w*)>([\S\s]*?)<\/\1>` but whilst it works for blocks of HTML it fails if the block contains a block of HTML with the same tags as the parent block. [Online example here](https://regex101.com/r/eK5dC6/6).

I'm using the PRCE variant of RegEx and coding in [Xojo](http://xojo.com).

Does anyone have any useful advice on how to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with this question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3603

Comment: It might be possible to match what you're aiming for _if_ you can guarantee a maximum depth of descendant elements. Then its just a matter of including an optional, repeating, expression for each depth.

Comment: An unsafe one like [`<(\w*)>(?:[^<]++|(?R))*<\/\1>`](https://regex101.com/r/eK5dC6/7) might do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That seems to pass the example test. Can you explain the unsafe nature of it?

Comment: The angle brackets can appear in other parts of HTML, not just to mark tags.

Comment: Ah, do you mean comments and CDATA? If so, could I make this safer if I remove them first?

Comment: The point is that there is no safe HTML parsing with regex. Use as is without any guarantee.

Comment: The failure of this logic is 1 that html is not necessarily nested. And 2, `<html> ---- </html>` is a large block. Once you match the large block, the next start position is after it.